# OCR app in android studio using Google Vision Api

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I have created a simple app for OCR with Google vision API.

My issue is that my images have **greek characters** and the app is recognizing them as english.
According to the documentation google vision api includes greek language https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages but it is suggested to provide a **LanguageHint** if there are issues with the language recognition.

I changed my code towards this post [How to setLanguageHint in Google OCR SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732951/how-to-setlanguagehint-in-google-ocr-sdk)

My issue is that the **ImageContext** class is not recognized. I imported `import com.google.cloud.vision.v1` but it also can't recognize this package.

```
ImageContext imageContext = ImageContext.newBuilder()
                .addLanguageHints("gr")
                .build();
```

I had also included in my gradle dependencies  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'` , and also tried to add `implementation com.google.cloud.vision.v1` but i got the following error

```
Supplied String module notation 'com.google.cloud.vision.v1' is invalid.
```

Could someone help me? Thank you

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: @Michael Thank you too much. I found the solution there